# Efficeint way to check if 35K + rows are present in table X having 700000+ rows?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 35K+ records (say column A) in a flat file. I have to check if these records are already present in table X (having 700000+ records)

- Column A is not an Indexed column in Table X. I do not have any column in Flat File which is indexed in X.

-I can't use the IN operator in SELECT because it is not a feasible option for 35+ records ( costly and limit being 1K)
- All the records have a similar pattern so I tried pattern match using LIKE operator in SELECT but it is very inefficient. ( the number of records with similar pattern in X is 120000+)
- I do not have create table privilege to insert in new table and subtract etc.

I am new to Oracle sorry if this question is naive. Also, I searched for similar questions and could not find answers for non-indexed columns.

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: If `one` row does not exist can you exit quickly?

Comment: Select * from A where X in ('...............');
select count(*) from X
where A like 'PRZ%' –- 116281

Comment: It's probably easier for you to get *create table privileges* than for us to help you on this one.

Comment: Did you try `not exists` or `JOIN`s? Ofcourse the flatfile should be loaded either through `SQLLDR` or `EXTERNAL TABLES`

Comment: If all the rows exist I have no problem but even if one row does not exist I would want to know which are the ones that do not exist.

Comment: You can store their IDs on another table for an efficient query.

Answer (score 1):

Flat file means text file like CSV or TSV? If it's just a text file, load it into database. Perhaps you can create a temporary table for this job. Then you can use the following query:

```
select * 
from x
where (c1, c2, ...) in (select c1, c2, ... from a);
```

Comment: @René Nyffenegger I convinced my DBA to grant me Create Table access and then checked using "IN". Thank you all for your help.